# Push everything from github repo to a fork and then create pull request

Tags: git, pull-request

I have a repo on github (lets call `repo-private`) that is private and I want to make its contents public by not going to settings and changing the privacy to public. I want to keep that privacy and my internals but want to create a simple public repo that contains work that is mature enough to be public.

For that I have created a new organization and in that created a new repo called `repo-public`, which only has `README.md` with the initial commit.

I fork this to my user account and name it `repo-public-develop`.

I go to my original `repo-private` in commandline and change its origin to `repo-public-develop` by:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo-public-develop.git`

Then: `git push -u origin main`

It pushes everything to `main` on the `repo-public-develop`.

Now I go to github and try to create a new pull request and there it says:

`There isn’t anything to compare.`
`repo-public:main` and `repo-public-develop:main` are entirely different commit histories.

Maybe my entire approach is wrong. Need help.

Thanks